# Customizing Emacs mode-line and command prompt

Tags: emacs

I am interested in customizing the Emacs display as much as possible, and wondered if it was possible to customize the layout of the Emacs mode-line and command prompt.

For example, I would like to move the command prompt and mode-line to the top of the window instead of the bottom.

Is this possible, and if so, how is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show a [header line](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Header-Lines.html#Header-Lines) that looks just like the mode line:

```
$ emacs --eval "(setq header-line-format mode-line-format)"
```

[Reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/hd15c/heres_what_you_actually_need_to_do_to_configure/) on how to customize the mode line.